# Is there one to one relation Positive definite(PD) matrix and PD function?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

Is it correct to say that a PD matrix can be built from a PD function? For example circulant matrix or Toeplitz seems to be built from a positive definite function. Positive definite function is defined in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function . My question is does every positive definite matrix have a corresponding positive definite function? For example there are positive definite matrix which is neither circulant nor Toeplitz, can we have some positive definite function to build such matrix?

Comment: Two matrices in the first line, not sure which should have been "function".

Comment: Any requirements at to the P.D. function domain?

Comment: @muaddib thank you modified it.

Comment: @Sasha no requirement I guess, but I do not understand what you mean by requirement.

Comment: @Creator - The question is hard for me to understand.  Matrices act on vectors, but the definition of positive definite function is something that acts on real numbers.  Can you clarify what you mean by correspondence, and/or "build such a matrix"?

Comment: @muaddib very good point. I am trying to understand the same question but in different form. In the wikipedia link the matrix element is written in terms of the function and so my question came in terms of built.

Comment: @Creator, gotcha, as defined in the "In Analysis" section.  Thanks.

Comment: @Creator Do you require the purported function to have any specific domain, like $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{S}^2$?

Comment: @Sasha Please do not get upset for asking what S means. I know R means real. I searched  for S in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols but could not find. Sorry. By the way I am not thinking of any domain yet, but I expect it to be complex (C) .

Comment: @Creator I meant sphere, plane, their subsets, or some other domains.

Comment: @Sasha, Thank you. Never thought in that direction, but somehow I was trying to associate it to the element of $L^1$ space, not sure if this statement makes sense.